# ManyToMany удаление Relation в Django

Tags: django

Есть модель Author, которая включена как ManyToMany в Book.
В результате работы некоторого кода была созданы книги, и соотносящиеся к ней авторы. В БД это выглядит вот так:

[image: таблица]

При обновлении книги необходимо у книги удалить некоторых авторов, при этом сами авторы должны как объекты продолжать жить в других книгах.

Не смог найти функции для данной задачи.
Функция должна удалить запись в таблице с нужным id (содержит в себе значения book_id и author_id). Но "не зверским", а в стиле django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то пошло не так, и у меня не работало как надо. 
На самом деле элементарное:

```
current_book.authors.remove(author)
```

То есть Realation удаляет remove (как ни странно) :)